# c++ library: application inserts a class in inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a library with the following inheritance hierarchy (a mock-up):

```
struct Xbase {
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : public Xbase {
    void f() { std::cerr << "Derived1::f\n"; }
};

struct Derived2 : public Xbase {
    void f() { std::cerr << "Derived2::f\n"; }
};
struct Storage {
    std::map<int, Xbase*> data;
    Xbase* get(int i) {
        auto it = data.find(i);
        return (it == data.end() ) ? nullptr : it->second;
    }
};
```

The library keeps track of pointers to base struct, and allows to retrieve them, in this small example by an integer id. There is an application that uses the library, and wants to provide some functionality by introducing a second base class Ybase:

```
struct Ybase {
    virtual void g() { std::cerr << "Ybase::g\n"; }
};

struct AppDerived1 : public Derived1, public Ybase {
    void f() { std::cerr << "AppDerived1::f\n"; }
};

struct AppDerived2 : public Derived2, public Ybase {
    void f() { std::cerr << "AppDerived2::f\n"; }
};
```

Of course things like

```
int i = 5;
Storage storage;
Xbase* xbase = storage.get(i);
Ybase* ybase = static_cast<Ybase *>(xbase);
```

do not work very well

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 t.cpp
t.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cpp:21:45: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘Xbase*’ to type ‘Ybase*’
```

I thought of providing a template version of derived classes so that the app developer could insert his class into the library hierarchy.

Library:

```
template<typename T>
struct Derived1 : public T {
    void f() { std::cerr << "Derived1::f\n"; }
};
```

App owner:

```
struct Ybase : public Xbase {
    virtual void g() { std::cerr << "Ybase::g\n"; }
};

struct AppDerived1 : public Derived1<Ybase> {
    ...
};
/* same for AppDerived2 */
Xbase* xbase = storage.get(i);
Ybase* ybase = static_cast<Ybase *>(xbase);
ybase->g();
```

This creates a single inheritance line, and the cast should work.

I'd like to understand if this is a good or a bad idea, and what could be the alternative.  Please note that I do need the common base class Xbase in the hierarchy because I have to be able to retrieve a base class pointer from external data like names and ids.  The problem for the app developer is that the app also needs its base pointer since the app does not know the type of the object (AppDerived1 or 2) it receives. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why not use dynamic_cast?

Comment: I could, but the gut feel is when I have to resort to dynamic_cast, it is time to change the design.

Comment: I don't think dynamic_cast is substantially different from static_cast in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preliminary remark:

You can't cast an `Xbase*` to an `Ybase*` as these are unrelated classes.
However, thanks to multiple inheritance and dynamic casting, you could safely convert from an Xbase to an Ybase if you know the most derived classes that could be used:

```
Ybase* ybase{};
Derived1 *pd1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(xbase);   // is it a Derived 1 ?  
if (pd1) {                                        // if yes
    AppDerived1 *app = dynamic_cast<AppDerived1*>(pd1); // Then look for an AppDerived 1
    if (app)                                      // If valid cast
        ybase = app;                              // we can cass the AppDerived1 to an Ybase
}
else {                                           // same approach for the second type 
    Derived2 *pd2 = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(xbase);   // is it a Derived 2 ?  
    if (pd2) {                                        // if yes
        AppDerived2 *app = dynamic_cast<AppDerived2*>(pd2);
        if (app)
            ybase = app;
    }
}  // if ybase is still nullptr here, it means that we couldn't find a valid conversion path
cout << (ybase ? "Success " : "Fail ") << (void*)ybase << endl;
```

This works making use of your object structure and legal up and down castings:
[image: AppDerived1-structure]

## Assessment of your alternative:

Your alernative is build on the principle to limit yourself to a single inheritance hierarchy.  The design of your class is completly different.  You assume that an Ybase **is-a** Xbase (always):

[image: Single-inheritance-alternative]

Whether this is good or not depends completely on the application domain that you try to represent.  If in reality an Ybase is always an Xbase, this would make perfect sense.

Here I can only quote Bjarne Stroustrup:

> Independent concepts should be independently represented and should be
> combined only when needed.  Where this principle is violated, you
> either bundle unrelated concepts together, or create unnecessary
> dependencies.  Either way you get less flexible set of components.